# How to select alternatively one column or the other

Tags: python, numpy

**What i wish to achieve :**

I'm looking to select alternatively (based on another array) a column or the other from a numpy array

**A reproducible example**

I have the following array

```
a = np.array([["a", "b"], 
              ["a", "b"], 
              ["a", "b"], 
              ["a", "b"]])
```

I wish to select using this conditions :

```
select = [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

What i wish to get :

```
np.array(["A",
          "B",
          "A",
          "B"])
```

**NB**

NB 1 : I know i could do it with a for loop, but it is not really efficient so I'm  looking for a better answer.

NB 2: I guess this is pretty simple, but I don't seem to have the right key words for google :/

NB 3 : This is a simple example, in the perfect world solution would work for any number of columns and with any number of dimensions (for example selection on axis n)

**Thanks**

Thanks for any help / pointers

Comment: Does each column always same element, duplicated? In such a case, why not `a[0][select]`?

Comment: You can always use `a.flatten()` which will give you almost what you're after, depending on whether the change in case was deliberate.

Comment: You are looking for something like `a[range(4),[0,1,0,1]]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this I think:

```
result = np.array([a[idx][selectElem] for idx, selectElem in enumerate(select)])
```

It's called list comprehension.